Find the nearest Keys that exists in the range boundary `[x,y]` in std::map in C++
I need to find the nearest keys in my map in a given range [x,y]. I am trying below
std::map<int, char> m{ {-2,'B'}, {1, 'C'},  {2, 'A'}};

auto itCurrent = m.lower_bound(-3);
auto itNext = m.upper_bound(-3);

auto it1 = m.lower_bound(3);
auto it2 = m.upper_bound(3);

I was hoping to get iterators that point to -2 and 2 by using lower_bound and uppper_bound around the enquiry boundary keys [-3,3]. it1 and it2 are returning end while itCurrent and itNext return iterator to key -2.
How do I get iterators to -2 and 2 as result?

Is it a typo that both bounds are '3'?

@User10482 no typo. [-3,3]

Can you post a [mcve]? itCurrent and itNext are iterators to pairs, they can't return -2.

@3CxEZiVlQ I have edited the question to make it more clearer iterator to Keys -2 and 2

Why not just use std::prev when you get the end iterator? You can make a function out of that. Also check that the map isn't empty.

lower_bound returns the first element not less than its argument. upper_bound returns the first element greater than its argument. They can't give you an element that is less than their argument.

@Nelfeal I can operate on a subset. That is just an example, it could be much biggermap.

I don't see the issue. Use lower_bound, check for end iterator or empty map, and then use std::prev.

If I understand the question correctly, you have a map m and two keys x and y, and you want the first element of m not less than x and the last element of m not greater than y.
The first is exactly what lower_bound gives you. That's itCurrent in your example. The second, you can easily get with lower_bound and std::advance.
auto inverse_lower_bound(auto const& map, auto const& key) {
    auto it = map.lower_bound(key);
    if (it == map.end() && !map.empty()) {
        std::advance(it, -1);
    }
    return it;
}

Demo
